# How to create a global hex grid

Tags: turf

I asked this question on SO, but now I realize that perhaps this is a more suitable forum. I need to generate a hex grid for the entire world and store it in my db.

Background: I have more than 300K lng/lat points and I would like to create a point-density map (heatmap). But instead of sending 300K+ points to the browser, I would like to bin them using a hex grid of a suitable size so the number of polys (in this case) to be sent to browser is more reasonable. I will play with the size of the grid, perhaps 200kms side, or even generate and store different size grids for different zoom levels. Hence, my need to generate this on the server and store it.

I am using `@turf/hex-grid` v 6.5.0 but getting nowhere.

```js
// area of 510M sq kms
const EARTH = 510000000; 

// https://www.math.net/area-of-a-hexagon
const hexarea = (side) => 3 * Math.sqrt(3) * side * side / 2;

const bbox = [-179.99, -90, 179.99, 90];
const options = { units: 'kilometers' };

const output = (side) => {
    const area_of_hex = hexarea(side);
    const grid = turf.hexGrid(bbox, side, options);
    
    console.log(`area of hexagon of side ${side} kms: ${area_of_hex}`);
    console.log(`number of hexagons to cover the earth: ${EARTH / area_of_hex}`);
    console.log(`num of hexagons generated by turf: ${grid.features.length}`);
    console.log(grid);
    console.log('----------------------------')
}

output(200);
output(1);
```

```
// output
area of hexagon of side 500 kms: 649519.052838329
number of hexagons to cover the earth: 785.1963660978911
num of hexagons generated by turf: 0
{ type: 'FeatureCollection', features: [] }
----------------------------
area of hexagon of side 1 kms: 2.598076211353316
number of hexagons to cover the earth: 196299091.52447274
num of hexagons generated by turf: 11555
{
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
  features: [
    { type: 'Feature', properties: {}, geometry: [Object] },
    { type: 'Feature', properties: {}, geometry: [Object] },
    … (98 more lines like above) …
    ... 11455 more items
  ]
}
```

Bafflingly, I can generate a global hex grid if I use `turf@2.0.0` available at //api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/turf/v2.0.0/turf.min.js (I saw a working example at http://muxlab.github.io/map-effects-100/Leaflet/10_hex-grid-with-turf.html code at https://github.com/muxlab/map-effects-100/blob/gh-pages/Leaflet/10_hex-grid-with-turf.html but that code uses a highly unintuitive cell side of `1` with units `kilometers`. As noted above, a hexagon of 1 km side would require more than 196299091 hexagons. But, `turf2.0.0` generates a reasonable number of hexagonal cells as seen in the map linked above.

I see there is an issue about this problem https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/issues/2199 but I am asking here in case someone can shed light on what is going on? Is there are better JS library? Are there limits to `bbox`? I realize the grid is going to be approximated toward the poles, but I don't mind going only as far out as practical.

Comment: I hinted by @obrl_soil in his short answer Uber created and opensourced an Hexagonal Hierarchical Spatial Index : H3 (https://eng.uber.com/h3/), you may want to investigate this first rather than trying to create an equivalent from scratch

Comment: What's interesting is that `turf.triangleGrid` works for side of 200 km.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a better time with [h3-js](https://github.com/uber/h3-js).